# Encoding Arabic Characters from MySQL to Xcode string

Tags: php, mysql, ios, xcode, utf-8

i have a MySQL database with MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
the tables inside the bd are utf8_general_ci collation

i get my result from the db using this php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar-sa">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styleNew.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title"  charset="utf-8">

<body>
<?php

include('newsDB.php');

mysql_set_charset('latin1');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id DESC");

$theID = "";
$theTITLE = "";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $theID = $theID . $row['id'] . "/i/";
    $theTITLE = $theTITLE . $row['caption'] . "/t/";
}

echo $theID . "+-+" . $theTITLE;

?>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

when i call the file from safari everything is fine, all the characters are in Arabic language

when i try to get the string from Xcode it can`t read the Arabic language

this is the code i`m using in Xcode

```
NSString *string = @"http://www.domain.com/file.php";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *data;
NSError *error;

data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] returningResponse: &response error: &error];

NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"strResult : %@",strResult);

tempArray = [strResult componentsSeparatedByString:@"+-+"];

NSLog(@"tempArray %@", tempArray);

NSString *tempID = [tempArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *tempTITLE = [tempArray objectAtIndex:1];

tempArrayID = [tempID componentsSeparatedByString:@"/i/"];
arrayID = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:tempArrayID];

tempArrayTITLE = [tempTITLE componentsSeparatedByString:@"/t/"];
arrayTITLE = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:tempArrayTITLE];

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

i also tried to change the encoding type in both php file and xcode

Xcode : latin1 , PHP : latin1
Xcode : utf8 , PHP : utf8
Xcode : latin1 , PHP : utf8
Xcode : utf8 , PHP : latin1

and still not showing the right Characters

any idea how to solve this ?

thank you in advance :)

**EDIT:**

i tried all the encoding in Xcode

```
NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
//NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding];
//NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSJapaneseEUCStringEncoding];
//NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSSymbolStringEncoding];
//NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
//NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSShiftJISStringEncoding];
//NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSISOLatin2StringEncoding];
//NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding];
//NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding];
//NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSWindowsCP1253StringEncoding];
//NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSWindowsCP1254StringEncoding];
//NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSWindowsCP1250StringEncoding];
//NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSISO2022JPStringEncoding];
//NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];
//NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];
//NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];
//NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
//NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSProprietaryStringEncoding];
```

**EDIT 2:**

Expected :
جانب من تدريبات منتخبنا لكرة السلة

Received :
ÌÇäÈ ãä ÊÏÑíÈÇÊ ãäÊÎÈäÇ áßÑÉ ÇáÓáÉ

Comment: changing the encoding of the file itself is pointless if the file contains a header saying it's `win-1256`...

Comment: @MarcB I removed everything in the php file and left it with only the php codes so no more html codes there, still the same problem and i even changed the encoding between the php file and Xcode

Comment: Have you tried to change encoding of the PHP file itself?

Comment: @Alex yes i did, i tried mysql_set_charset('latin1') and mysql_set_charset('utf8') and even removed the encoding

Comment: mysql_set_charset will set encoding for database connection, but PHP file has encoding of it's own, e.g. in Coda it's called Text Encoding.

Comment: @Alex can you please provide me with an example with my above code ? i`m not that good in php

Comment: Actually there is no code, you should change the encoding of the file.php itself (format how text is written in the file). Usually you do that from your text editor, TextWrangler, Coda, Sublime...

Comment: @Alex ok i did saved it with utf8 and nothing changed

Comment: It was worth to try :) Can you update your question with expected and received chars?

Comment: @Alex Done updating :)

Comment: Put this as first line in your PHP file: header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54308/discussion-between-alex-and-alfarsi).